# Linear Independence and Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, wronskian

The question is:

> Suppose that $~f~$ and $~g~$ are linearly independent functions on the real line.
>
> Prove that there exists $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $W(f,g)(t_0) \neq 0$.

This seems rather simple, but I am having trouble putting together a solid proof. Any suggestions for a starting point?

I know that linear independence means the matrix of $~f~$ and $~g~$ will have a non-zero determinate, but how do I apply this to the Wronskian?

Comment: You trying to prove a false statement. Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x|x|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $W(f,g)(t)=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, this means the matrix
$$A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}f(t) & g(t)\\
f'(t) &g'(t)\end{bmatrix}$$
is singular for every $t$. Then what can you say about the columns of $A(t)$?

Comment: You could say the columns are linearly dependent, correct? @Frank Lu

Comment: So this proof could work by contradiction? @Frank Lu

Comment: That's the point.

Comment: There's a distinction between contradiction and contrapositive. This example falls in the latter category.

Answer (score -1):

If $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $W(f,g)(t) = 0$ so
$$W(f,g)=‎\left|\begin{array}{rr}f&g\\f'&g'\end{array}\right|=0$$
so ‎$$\dfrac{f'}{f}=\dfrac{g'}{g}$$
shows
$$\ln f=\ln Cg$$
for a constant $C$, this means $f=Cg$.

Comment: This is true only if $f(x)\neq0$ and $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x$. Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x|x|$.